# Property or method "contact" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render Vuejs Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.7

I'm developing chat app on laravel using vue.js and i'm new to vue.js.

but i'm getting below mentioned error, please help me solve this

Error1 :
[Vue warn]: Property or method "contact" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

Error2 :
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of undefined"

/ ChatApp.vue file/

```
    <template>
    <div class="chat-app">
    <Conversation :contact="selectedContact" :messages="messages"/>
    <ContactsList :contacts="contacts"/>
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import Conversation from './Conversation.vue';
    import ContactsList from './ContactsList.vue';

    export default {
    props: {
        user: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },  
    data(){
        return {
            selectedContact: null,
            messages: [],
            contacts: []
        };
    },        
    mounted(){
        axios.get('/contacts')
        .then((response) => {
            this.contacts = response.data;
        });
    },
    methods: {
        startConversationWith(contact) {
            axios.get(`/conversation/$(contact.id)`)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.messages = response.data;
                    this.selectedContact = contact;
                })
        }
    },
    components: { ContactsList, Conversation }
    };
    </script>
```

/ ContactsList.vue file/

```
    <template>
    <div class="contacts-list">
    <ul v-if="contacts.length > 0">
        <li v-for:"(contact, index) In contacts" :key="contact.id" 
    @click="selectContact(index, contact)" :class="{ 'selected' : index == 
    selected}">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img :src="contact.avatar" :alt="contact.name">
            </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <p class="name">{{ contact.name }}</p>
                <p class="email">{{ contact.email }}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
    props: {
    contacts: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    }
    },
    data() {
     return {
        selected: 0
     };
    },
    methods: {
     selectContact(index, contact) {
         this.selected = index;
         this.$emit('selected', contact);
     }
    }
    };
    </script>
```

/ conversation.vue /

```
    <template>
    <div class="conversation">
    <h1>{{ contact ? contact.name : 'Select a contact' }}</h1>
    <MessagesFeed :contact="contact" :messages="messages" />
    <MessageComposer @send="sendMessage" />
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import MessagesFeed from './MessagesFeed.vue';
    import MessageComposer from './MessageComposer.vue';

    export default {
     props: {
        contact: {
            type: Object,
            default: null
        },
        messages: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        }
    },
    methods:{
        sendMessage(text) {
            console.log(text);
        }
    },
    components: {MessagesFeed, MessageComposer}
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Akash you can use it this way :

```
data() {
    return {
        contactsNotEmpty:false
    }
},
// ...
mounted() {
     axios.get('/contacts')
        .then((response) => {
            this.contacts = response.data;
            this.contactsNotEmpty = true;
        });
}
```

---

```
<ul v-if="contactsNotEmpty">
    ...
</ul>
```

also you may check this vuejs article about what is happening : https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do it like that:

```
<ul v-if="contacts.length > 0">
    <li v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.id">
        <div class="avatar">
             <img :src="contact.avatar" :alt="contact.name">
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
             <p class="name">{{ contact.name }}</p>
             <p class="email">{{ contact.email }}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: just a suggestion if you would try `<ul v-if="contactsNotEmpty"` this boolean variable switch to `true` when you finish loading you api call

Comment: @ElAlamiAnas thank you, but it shows

Property or method "contactsNotEmpty" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is throwing in your `Conversation.vue`, you were passing data to a child component, you have to make sure it is defined as a prop in that component

`export default{
props: ['contact']
};`

and if it is defined, your `prop type` is not expecting a null value. I would change it to string and on rendering in my `ChatApp.vue`, I would set `selectedContact` to string.Empty||''

For the second error, the avatar key is missing from your response object. You have to check if it is present first before accessing it. Kindly refer to El Alami Anas's answer above.

Comment: For you i have added conversation.vue file. Thank you

Comment: Your data for contact prop in coversation.vue expects an object, you are passing a null value into it.. In your ChatApp.vue, change `selectedContact ` to `{}`. Change your default type to `{}` in Conversation.vue for the `contact` prop

Comment: Still refer to @El Amani answer for your typeerror on why avatar is undefined