# 1894 Uncaught ReferenceError: vur is not defined at Module../resources/js/app.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using laravel and vue , but when i try to load the page, this error appear

```
 app.js:1894 Uncaught ReferenceError: vur is not defined
               at Module../resources/js/app.js
```

my webpack file is:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.vue()
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

my route file is:

```
   import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
export default({
    mode:'history',

    routes:[
        {
            path: '/',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            component: About
        },
    ]
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your app.js and index.js files.You may have spelled vue as vur.It's a typo I think.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved, there is no longer an error, but why is the data in the Home.vue page not showing in the welcome.blade.php page?

Comment: it's a late reply.in your welcome.blade file make a div with id="root".in your app.js file look for el and make it el:'root' and render the component.

Comment: hello, i did that but the problem still appear

Comment: what is the console message?

Comment: this is the problem, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67176102/array-to-string-conversion-while-passing-data-from-laravel-to-vue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478303/property-or-method-contact-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-but-referenced-durin check this