# Property or method "article" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive

Tags: vue.js

Hello i'm try to passing data from controller to vue ,but when the page is load this error appears in the console:

```
app.js:42786 [Vue warn]: Property or method "article" is not defined on the
```

instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
initializing the property. See:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

```
found in

---> <ListAllArticles> at resources/js/components/ListAllArticles.vue
       <App> at resources/js/components/app.vue
         <Root>
```

my route is:

```
Route::resource('article',[ArticleController::class]);
```

my vue file is:

```
 <template>
    <div class="articles">
        <p>this file to list all article</p>
        <div>
            <div :v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id">{{article.name}}</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            articles:''
        }
    },
    methods:{
   getArticle(){
       axios.get('api/article').then((res) =>{
           this.articles = res.data
             }).catch((error)=>{
                 console.log(error)
             })
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getArticle()
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.articles{
    background-color: gray;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I haven't used Laravel in a while, but your route code looks like it might be PHP/Laravel.  Vue has no knowledge of what is defined in your PHP code.  You need to define 'artlcle' in Vue.  And not sure if you realize that client side Vue routing and server side Laravel routing are two different things with no common data.